# How to display text in a dynamically created textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm creating a textarea on click of a button with jQuery. The problem I have is that the textarea value does not display, tho I can see in the console that the value has been set. How can I make this work and display text in a dynamically created textarea?

```js
$('.createTextButton').click(function() {

  var mailbody = 'Hello, how are you?';


  $('<textarea>').attr({
    id: 'demomailbody',
    class: 'form-control',
    name: 'demomailbody',
    value: mailbody
  }).appendTo('#pf4');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
          <span>Body</span>
          </label>
  <p id="pf4"></p>
</div>

<button class="createTextButton">Create</button>
```

What I see in the Inspector
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nclZL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is actually a property and not an attribute. Use `.val()` to set the text. Or you could (but not recommended) use `.prop('value', mailbody)`

```js
$('.createTextButton').click(function() {
  var mailbody = 'Hello, how are you?';
  $('<textarea>')
    .attr({
      id: 'demomailbody',
      class: 'form-control',
      name: 'demomailbody'
    })
    .val(mailbody)
    .appendTo('#pf4');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <span>Body</span>
  </label>
  <p id="pf4"></p>
</div>

<button class="createTextButton">Create</button>
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer. Thank you. I should have looked more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Textareas do **not** have a value attribute.

```js
$('.createTextButton').click(function() {

  var mailbody = 'Hello, how are you?';


  $('<textarea>').attr({
    id: 'demomailbody',
    class: 'form-control',
    name: 'demomailbody'
  }).appendTo('#pf4');
  
  $('textarea').text(mailbody).appendTo('#pf4');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
          <span>Body</span>
          </label>
  <p id="pf4"></p>
</div>

<button class="createTextButton">Create</button>
```

Comment: And if they create more than one? You than select every one and set the text... and you really should not be setting text

Answer (score -1):

**$("textarea").html("Your Text");**

OR

**$("textarea").text("Your Text");**

You can use above code for it.

jsfiddle.net/cLsd39e1/

Comment: you do not use html for textarea